# avoid Number Format Exception while parseing to integer

Tags: number-formatting

I'm trying to check if the text area has only numbers or not, but i got this problem Number Format Exception while clicking on the Edit Button, any Ideas how to solve it.

```
ArrayList<CarRental> List= CarRent.getList();

String text=EditTF.getText().trim();

 char [] txt=text.toCharArray();

 Character a=null;

  boolean isnotDigit=false;

int index;

    for(int i=0;i<txt.length;i++)
    {
        if(!a.isDigit(txt[i]))
        {
            isnotDigit=true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            isnotDigit=false;
            continue;
        }
    }

    if(isnotDigit==false)
    {
        index=Integer.parseInt(text.trim());
        PrintList_Summary.setIndex(index);
        EditDetails.nameTF.setText(List.get(index).getName());
        EditDetails.sizeCOB.setSelectedItem(List.get(index).getSize());        
        EditDetails.daysTF.setText(List.get(index).getDays()+"");

        if(List.get(index).getCarType().equalsIgnoreCase("Luxury"))
        {
            EditDetails.LuxRB.setSelected(true);
        }
        else if(List.get(index).CarType().equalsIgnoreCase("Truck"))
        {
            EditDetails.truckRB.setSelected(true);
        }

        if(List.get(index).getDriver())
        {
            EditDetails.yesRB.setSelected(true);
        }
        else
        {
            EditDetails.noRB.setSelected(true);
        }

        EditDetails.Frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane warning=new JOptionPane();
        warning.showMessageDialog(null,"Element Index CAN ONLY be an INTEGER.","Invalid Index",WIDTH);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add a tag for the language, I'm assuming it's Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch to handle exceptions.

```
try{
    index = Integer.parseInt(text.trim());
    //etc
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    //whatever happens when the exception is thrown (not an integer)
}
```

You can use that instead of the if(!a.isDigit(txt[i])) for.  If it can't be parsed, then it will go intro the catch.

Also, you can use !isnotDigit instead of isnotDigit == false.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) for your check instead of doing it yourself. Scrap the for-loop and change your if-condtion from `isnotDigit==false` to `text.matches("[0-9]+")`. After this `Integer.parseInt(text)` should definitly work.

This uses a regular expression to check if your string consists only of digits and at least one digit. For further reference on regular expression see the [javadoc for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: i used the text.matches() it was free of Number Format Exception, BUT it works every first time i click the button then any second ,third, fourth, and so on attempts, they fire the esle statment instead the (if statment) even if the input is an integer.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what the value is and where it comes from.